# Bullets not showing in game view in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm making a "space shooter" game in Unity and here is my problem;

When the spaceship fires, the bullets are created. I can see them on the hierarchy screen, but the bullets are not visible in the "game view". When I switch to the "Scene view" and check it, I see that the bullets are there and moving at the top layer. Here are what I've done so far:

*Raised the sorting layer of the bullets (didn't work)

*Raised the sorting layer of the spaceship (didn't work)

*I turned off the parallax effect on my camera (there was only blank screen and spaceship and it didn't work)

*I checked the layers from the scene screen. (Everything is as it should be but still hasn't worked)

In addition, I placed a bullet from my prefabs in the scene. I can see that bullet when I run the game, but the bullets I shoot by pressing the space key are not visible.

Screenshots of the problem:

[image: GameView]

[image: SceneView]

The code I use is:

PlayerController:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    private float min_Y = -4.2f, max_Y = 4.6f;
    private float min_Z = -.8f, max_Z = -.6f;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject PlayerBullet;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform AttackPoint;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MovePlayer();
        Attack();
    }


    void MovePlayer()
    {
        if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0f)
        {
            Vector3 temp = transform.position;
            Quaternion temp2 = transform.rotation;
            temp.y += speed * Time.deltaTime;
            temp2.z += speed * Time.deltaTime;

            if (temp2.z > max_Z)
                temp2.z = max_Z;

            if (temp.y > max_Y)
                temp.y = max_Y;

            transform.rotation = temp2;
            transform.position = temp;
        }
        else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0f)
        {
            Quaternion temp2 = transform.rotation;
            Vector3 temp = transform.position;
            temp.y -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
            temp2.z -= speed * Time.deltaTime;

            if (temp2.z < min_Z)
                temp2.z = min_Z;

            if (temp.y < min_Y)
                temp.y = min_Y;

            transform.rotation = temp2;
            transform.position = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Quaternion temp2 = transform.rotation;
            if(temp2.z > -0.71f)
            {
                temp2.z -= speed/2 * Time.deltaTime;
                if (temp2.z < -0.71f)
                    temp2.z = -0.71f;
            }
            else if (temp2.z < -0.71f)
            {
                temp2.z += speed/2 * Time.deltaTime;
                if (temp2.z > -0.71f)
                    temp2.z = -0.71f;
            }

            transform.rotation = temp2;
        }
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Instantiate(PlayerBullet, AttackPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

BulletScript:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 7f;
    private float DeactivateTimer = 3f;
    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 temp = transform.position;
        temp.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = temp;
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me I would be appreciated...

Comment: Could not be the source of the problem at all, but just as a comment, the z coord seems a little bit weird with all that decimal numbers. It would make more sense to me to keep a z as a round number like -10, or 0. I would also try with a Z clearly closer to the camera (like -5 between the camera and the backroud) to check if the bullet shows up in the game screen and if the z coordinate of the objects in the scene might be a problem.

Comment: The reason to use the Z coordinate that way is to make the spaceship "leaning" in that direction when moving it up or down. The lean effect has no effect on the bullets since the bullets I fired come out of a gameobject in front of the spaceship.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now! Your script is clearly `c#`!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! The created bullets has -9 in transform.z. Fixed it replacing them with 0. Such a stupid msitake...